# Como marcar em negrito caracteres sequencialmente triplicados e quadruplicados de uma string?

Tags: php, javascript

Quero marcar as sequências triplicadas e quadruplicadas de uma *string* como esta:

```
$string = "AAACDEAAAABBBUUDD";
```

E gostaria de obter como resultado o seguinte:

```
<b>AAA</b>CDE<b>AAAA</b><b>BBB</b>UUDD
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Versão PHP

```
   $string = 'AAACDEAAAABBBUUDD';
   $bold = preg_replace( '/(.)\1{2,}/', '<b>$0</b>' , $string );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/jxPOax)**

### Versão JavaScript

```
var str = "AAACDEAAAABBBUUDD";
var res = str.replace( /(.)\1{2,}/g, "<b>$&</b>");
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/MQSNca)**

### Entendendo a RegEx

- `(.)` = qualquer caractere (troque por `(\S)` se não quiser espaços);
- `\1` = o caractere referido anteriormente pelo primeiro grupo `(.)`;
- `{2,}` duas ou mais ocorrências do caractere anterior. Se somente quiser sequências de três ou quatro caracteres, desconsiderando cinco ou mais, substitua por `{2,3}` (original mais dois iguais, ou original mais três iguais).

Ou seja, a cada caractere iterado, verificamos se é seguido por mais 2 ocorrências do mesmo, totalizando as 3 ou mais pretendidas.

A substituição `<b>$0</b>` (`$&` em JS) pega o conjunto todo encontrado, e acrescenta o *bold*.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: só complementando.
Caso existam 3 ou mais espaços também ocorrerá a substituição. 
Se em alguma string possa ocorrer isso recomendo usar a ER 
(.(?!\s+))\1{2,}
Testando aqui https://regex101.com/r/UDabwC/1/
@Pedro
Recomendo ler http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/retrovisor.html

Comment: @MarcosXavier é uma observação válida, mas se ele não quiser espaços `(\S)\1{2,}` já é suficiente: https://regex101.com/r/UDabwC/2 - de qualquer forma, melhorei a resposta com base no seu comentário, grato.

Comment: @Bacco ótimo, comentei para agregar mesmo.